# Converting Hyperledger Fabric query block responses to human readable form

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

If I use the nodejs sdk to do the following:

`return chain.queryBlock(4);`

The response returned is in the format:

`"data_hash": {
        "buffer": {
          "type": "Buffer",
          "data": [
            10,
            70,
            8,
            4,
            18,
            32,
            14,
            11,
            73,
            154,
            161,
            251,
            77,
            145,
            112,
            103,
            75,
            10,
            151,
            155,
            127,
            74,
            31,
            25,
            135,
            170,`

Where data is in a byte format. How could I convert this to a human readable format, maybe json format to see the list of transactions and associated data in this block. I would like to achieve similar functionality to Hyperledger's `Blockchain Explorer` where you can see list of blocks and list of transactions in a given block.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use [BlockDecoder](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/BlockDecoder.html#.decodeTransaction__anchor),

```
BlockDecoder.decodeBlock(block)
```

there is quite good documentation for NodeSDK APIs and a few example which you can use, [here](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the configtxgen command as below...

configtxgen -inspectBlock path_to_your_block

Comment: How to dump block data into a file?

Comment: this is not right approach to see content of the block for your application, configtxgen purpose is to generate initial setup for given chain. and inspectBlock option is to be able to verify content of genesis block produced.

Answer (score 0):

`BlockDecoder` probably has already run at this point to convert from `protobuf` 
You can use `toString()` on data